# Parallax scrolling on slider jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, web, parallax

I'm trying to use a full screen slider that has a parallax scroll effect when I scroll down on a website, but all the parallax effects are applying on images and not the whole div or slider.

Comment: Please include your code and HTML, so we can help you identify the issue.

Comment: basicly its like <div Class="fullpage slider"><div/> and i want this full page slider is have a parallax effect in scroling down like scrollout' slideout to up and etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery libraries for your parallax effect, here are some that are popular:

- [jQuery-Parallax](https://github.com/IanLunn/jQuery-Parallax)
- [Jparallax](http://stephband.info/jparallax/)

You can also use pure CSS parallax solution using `perspective` ant `transform` CSS3 properties, here is an [example](http://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw) and tutorials:

- [Pure CSS parallax scrolling websites](https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-parallax-scrolling-websites/)
- [Pure CSS Parallax Websites](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/)

Comment: asicly its like <div Class="fullpage slider"><div/> and i want this full page slider is have a parallax effect in scroling down like scrollout' slideout to up and etc